# Why does `env -i` fail to ignore my environment?

Tags: linux, environment-variables

Acknowledgement: Maybe I'm misunderstanding what "environment" means.

The [man page for `env`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/env.1.html) claims that `env - [command]` (or `env -i [command]`) should run `command` in an empty environment. Testing this behavior, `PATH` is an environment variable (i.e. a part of an "environment"). But, alas:

```
➜  ~ env - echo $PATH
/home/user/.nvm/versions/node/v15.3.0/bin:/home/user/.deno/bin:/usr/local/lib/node/nodejs/bin:/home/user/.nix-profile/bin:/nix/var/nix/profiles/default/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin
```

is the same as

```
➜  ~ echo $PATH
/home/user/.nvm/versions/node/v15.3.0/bin:/home/user/.deno/bin:/usr/local/lib/node/nodejs/bin:/home/user/.nix-profile/bin:/nix/var/nix/profiles/default/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin
```

So, what's going on? This happens for a few other environment variables, too, like `$SHELL` and `$USER`.

So, can someone define "environment" and what `env` *actually* does when using `env - [command]` or `env -i [command]`.

Note that `env - PATH= echo $PATH` produces the expected result of failing to find `echo` on the path. But, it's weird to me that I have to explicitly set that environment variable to an empty string since I'm ostensibly clearing my environment prior to running `[command]`.

Bonus confusion:

`env env` prints all of my environment's variables while `env - env` produces empty output (makes sense... environment should be `i`gnored, but this seems inconsistent with `env - echo $PATH` printing my environment's `PATH`.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In `env -i echo $PATH`, the variable is expanded by your shell, so the `env` program never sees the variable.

You can spawn a child shell to inspect variables; use quotes to prevent evaluation by the parent shell:

```
A=1 env -i sh -c 'echo $A' # prints nothing
A=1 env    sh -c 'echo $A' # prints 1
A=1 env    printenv A      # prints 1
```

PATH is special. Even if you delete it from your environment, your shell will probably define a fallback path. That one is not exported to child processes but only visible as shell variable.

```
env -i printenv PATH       # prints nothing, PATH is no longer exported
env -i sh -c 'echo $PATH'  # prints something like /sbin:/bin
```